# IFC conversion method changes position of resulting SVF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When converting IFC files to SVF with the [Autodesk Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/), I would like to start using the "modern" converter instead of the "legacy" one. However, when using Forge Viewer, the models that were created with the modern conversion method end up with a different position and/or orientation than the legacy ones.

I have tried to get to the bottom of what the difference consists of, and it seems to at least have something to do with the `TrueNorth` property of the `IfcRepresentationContext` in the `IfcProject`. Also, the `ObjectPlacement` of the `IfcSite` is probably part of it. But I haven't found a combination of properties to reliably compensate for the difference for all my IFC files. The IFCs typically come from Revit, but may have various origins.

Many of our customers have projects with several existing models, so ideally, any new models should align with the existing ones even if the conversion method has changed.

Comment: I'm checking with our engineering team, and. will get back to you A.S.A.P.

Comment: I submitted an issue item NWLMV-164 on your behalf to ask our engineering team to allocate time to investigate it. I will get back to you once I got responses from them. Thanks!

Comment: @EasonKang Any news on this?

Comment: Our engineering team is working on it, but it would take time to fix it. So, please refer to my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an issue item NWLMV-164 on your behalf to ask our engineering team to allocate time to investigate it. Now it can be traced back to NWLMV-88. As result, it needs some time to explore and find the solution to fix this issue. Please take a note of either NWLMV prefix ids. You're welcome to track updates in the future by sending an email to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com quoting the NWLMV prefix ids. We appreciate your understanding and patience.